# How to Uninstall dsnmasq completely and what are the side effects of doing so?

Tags: 14.04, dnsmasq

I don't want dsnmasq running all the time. I want to uninstall it. How to do it? I also found this link(http://overtag.dk/wordpress/2014/06/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-with-dns-server-and-networkmanager-disabling-dnsmasq/). Can i follow the instructions mentioned in here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have/need a wifi hotspot (like `ap-hotspot`), or something else that requires another machine to ask yours for DNS?

Comment: No, its not like that. I am connected to a wireless dongle.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't your computer to host a DNS cache/server for something - e.g. for a WiFi hotspot using `ap-hotspot`, you can simply remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq
```

As far as I know, it is not needed by default in most Ubuntu installs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine what  `man dnsmasq` says about its purpose:

> Dnsmasq  accepts  DNS  queries  and  either  answers them from a
>   small,
>          local, cache or forwards them to a  real,  recursive,  DNS  server.  It
>          loads  the  contents of /etc/hosts so that local hostnames which do not
>          appear in the global DNS can be resolved and also answers  DNS  queries
>          for  DHCP  configured  hosts.  It can also act as the authoritative DNS
>          server for one or more domains, allowing local names to appear  in  the
>          global DNS. It can be configured to do DNSSEC validation.

So if you do not need:

- to read particular ip addresses saved in `/etc/hosts`
- use local DNS cache
- use your machine as DHCP server

removing `dnsmasq` won't affect you.

Personally, I have `dnsmasq` commented out in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and use my own DNS server in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

Comment: Ok, I trust you ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended directly by Steam as a workaround for their slow download speeds in Ubuntu. Steam caps out at 28mbps download speed and I have 200mbs connection. Terminal gets 150mbs using fast command, speedtest.com shows getting speeds of up to 225mbps.

So that's quite a big drop. At first I thought it was just my lan configuration was wrong or ethernet drivers were wrong, but apparently it is just a Steam issue.

The steam article is 6 years old, so seems like this has been an ongoing issue for past six years??

Excerpt:

Due to a bug in the Steam for Linux client it can slow down not only its own download speeds, but all DNS using network activity at the same time. This happens because the client looks up the network address for all the download servers it connects to every time it makes a connection. This can mean it will request the same information ten times a second from the DNS servers your network connection is using. Depending on how that DNS server is configured, it can throttle down the amount of DNS requests you can make. This causes Steam download speeds to start fast, but then quickly slow down into nothing, before starting up again fast for a short while.

Full site workaround:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/616189106498372437/

So there is a use for it in 20.04. Unless you don't use Steam or do the things other's mentioned above...